# proof by contradiction of rational numbers

Tags: logic

I am trying to proof by contradiction the following statement: "Every integer is rational", so far I have done the following:

I can convert the expression to "If $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ then $n\in \mathbb{Q}$" so that I can have it the form $p\rightarrow q$.
For what I know in a contradition proof I should negate q and if I assume that p is true then I should end up with a contradiction in this term.
So I can say that n is an irrational or that $n\in \mathbb{I}$. For this to hold I should assume that n cannot be represented as the ratio of two numbers p and q, but this is a contradiction with
$n\in \mathbb{Z}$ because if n is integer there should be result of a ratio of two integer numbers.

I would like to know is this proof is correct or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't see any content here.  You appear to be arguing that since integers are rational they can't be irrational. But if course the rationality of integers is what you are asked to prove.

Comment: Since you already seem to be aware that any integer $n$ can be written as $\frac n1$ and is therefore rational, I see no point at all in further argument.

Comment: thank you @lulu for your comments, I know that the proof can be made by direct way, but I have doubts how to do it using a contradiction proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you do it by contradiction:

Let $n \in \Bbb Z$. Suppose $n\not\in \Bbb Q$. That means $n$ can't be written as a quotient of two integers, but $n=n/1$. A contradiction.

Comment: thanks @jjagmath, It was really straighforward

Answer (score 1):

Since the concept and property of both integer and rational are quite elementary, to complete as a formal logic proof, you only need ∀ introduction rule by first picking an arbitrary integer $n$ from its default domain of discourse as a subproof step in your formal derivation, no need for indirect proof by contradiction (aka negation introduction rule).

If you really want the other way around, the negation of $∀x(Z(x)→R(x))$ is $∃x(Z(x)∧¬R(x))$. So after assuming this in your formal subproof, you can use ∃ elimination rule to instantiate a constant integer n and n is irrational, then you can easily arrive at falsity ⊥ via the properties of irrationals and integer. Then your negation introduction subproof part can be finished and returned to arrive at your final conclusion. This is called (Fitch style) formal proof using natural deduction.

Comment: This answer would be better if it was written at a slightly lower level. You bring up a good point about how to negate conditionals, but it gets lost due to all the technical jargon. The author is not seeking a formal logic proof.

Comment: @Isaiah thx for your suggestion. I'm providing a more formal perspective. Beyond this elementary exercise/homework, a serious student can have the opportunity to hear and learn more... I believe the logical deduction habit is more important than the problem itself in this case and OP's confusion is exactly in logic not those integer/irrational simple maths.